# SSIS 2012 package to loop through csv files doesn't run on server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I've created an ssis package following this template here:

[loop through flat files](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

It works fine, I have referred to my folder which contains the csv files with its full network path.  If I upload it to the server and schedule it, it executes with no errors but nothing happens so I am sure it is not finding the folder and assuming it is empty and therefore there is no work to do.  I'm running the package as a proxyAgent and The folder with the csv files is accessible by the credentials of my account.

Any ideas how what might be going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try adding a Script Task to show some text in the For Each container. That will help you know if the loop itself is not run or if the DFT has issues.

Comment: I have already added a SQL task at the end and that runs fine. I think the issue must be because the scheduled agent can't see my csv folder. How can I find out what thing needs access to my folder?

Comment: You could check folder permissions and share permissions for the account used to run.

Comment: Thanks - thats it. d'oh - simple error I thought I'd given permission to the credential account but I hadn't.